Building a "real-time" outbox pattern on Python / SQLALchemy
I have create a outbox messages in my FastAPI/SQLAlchemy/Postgres application. The application is hosted in GCP. Now I need to publish this events, "reading" from the outbox table. I need to have this events to be published in real time.
What are the options that i have?

A Cron that will read these messages and published it. The problem with this solution is the messages could be delayed. for the sake of nature of a cron job.
Use a CDC, like GCP Datastream. It seems complex as as Datastream GCP still doesnt have a simple way to move these messages to pub/sub. Actually we need to move the messages for a GCP storage, and process from there.
Debezium. The problem is that it will be a new moving piece in my architecture, that we need to manage.


how about using postgreSQL triggers ? take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680356/is-it-possible-to-publish-a-message-to-google-pub-sub-whenever-a-data-is-inserte

If the notification failes, Does postgres will retry? In this solution,  I suppose that we still have a dual writter problem.

what would cause the trigger to fail ? pg is a relatively stable tool, your retry system should be in the pubsub part anyway
