# How to test Cloud Function in GCP where I am inserting data into Database

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test this function which inserts data into postgres via GCP **Cloud Function**. I am having trouble testing this. It say some JSON is required. However what is exactly required her to be called?

```
def hello_world(self):
# establishing the connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database='somedb',
    user='someuser',
    password='somepwd',
    host='XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    port='5432'
)

# creating a cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

# list that contain records to be inserted into table
data = [('Babita', 'Bihar'), ('Anushka', 'Hyderabad'),
        ('Anamika', 'Banglore'), ('Sanaya', 'Pune'),
        ('Radha', 'Chandigarh')]

# inserting record into employee table
for d in data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT into employee(name, state) VALUES (%s, %s)", d)


# print("List has been inserted to employee table successfully...")

# Commit your changes in the database
conn.commit()

# Closing the connection
conn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcp - Trigger Cloud Function on database insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352899/gcp-trigger-cloud-function-on-database-insert)